# Rewrite url to correct wrong url

Tags: url-rewriting

I discovered that a plugin created an incorrect link to some resources on my site (link to comments) with the result that many crawlers are looking for non-existent urls
like this: `page.htmlcomment-12345`
instead of this: `page.html#comment-12345`

I need to correct the url by inserting the # but preserving the number at the end which corresponds to the comment ID.

Is it possible to do this with .htaccess or a regular expression on CloudFlare?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a regex substitution:

- Regex: `((?:.*)\.html)(?!#)(.+)`
- Substitution: `$1#$2`

`((?:.*)\.html)(?!#)(.+)`

- `((?:.*)\.html)` - match the URL up to ending with .html and group it
- `(?!#)` - Check no `#` is present
- `(.+)` - and more text available and group it

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gxZi0j/1)